# Multi Input Password functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am searching about the functionality like filtered inputs for the password. I need a functionality where the user will inputs their password in four diff-diff inputs as password.

I have device gem with me, But Is it possible to have that functionality with that gem.

If any other gems available then, please share with me to get solve my issues.

Please refer the attached below images for getting the idea in more details........

[image: password]